# How to use CountChanged from within Idle loop correctly

Tags: mimekit

How I am supposed to use Fetch in CountChanged event from within Idle loop? I saw the demo where there is a comment to cancel the idle loop.

However if I do that -

```
async void CountChanged(...)
{
    await Task.Run(() => idleToken.Cancel())
    Fetch(...)
}
```

Fetch will be executed async and potentially after any MessageExpunge event. That can mess up local index which might expect CountChange to have already updated the local cache index.

- 4 EXPUNGE
- 3 EXISTS - CountChange event here can be executed after * 3 EXPUNGE below and that will mess up the index
- 3 EXPUNGE

Please advice?

Answer (score 1):

This is not only an issue with idle. This applies for every command that can emit EXISTS unsolicited response. What I did is instead of executing code from inside the event handlers, I am using a CommandQueue where I am adding Actions which is the code supposed to be executed inside the event handlers. After the Mailkit/Imap command completes, I am executing the CommandQueue actions in the same order I've received them in the same thread synchronously. Overall the Mailkit library is very nice and congratulation for the great work.

Comment: If MailKit waited for the command to finish before emitting events, then what would be the point of the IDLE command if you have to call idleToken.Cancel() before it emitted events?

Comment: yes, that makes sense. I guess I have to live with that :)

Comment: FWIW, a command queue is a good way of solving this problem. I would have mentioned it, but it's more complicated than the dead-simple solution I suggested above and is not something the average StackOverflow user would know how to do w/o spending a lot of time explaining how to write one.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is use 2 ImapClient instances. One that just does IDLE and one that does the fetching when the message count changes.

Your other option:

```
void CountChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    countChanged = true;
    idleToken.Cancel ();
}
```

Then:

```
await client.IdleAsync (idleToken, cancelToken);
if (countChanged) {
    client.Fetch (...);
}
```

Comment: Is it safe to re-order CountChanged event that way? With that code if I receive events in that order 1,2,3,4,5,6 where 4 is the CountChanged, if I apply that solution the events will be executed in this order 1,2,3,5,6,4.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by 1,2,3,4,5,6. The order of your operations is all up to you.

Comment: I thought the order of unsolicited response does matter but I guess I am wrong.